# can we a prove ⊢ (α → α) → (α → α)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

The system L0 is defined as follows:

Axioms:
A1 (α → (β → α))

A2 2. (α → (β → γ) → ((α → β) → (α → γ))

A3 ((¬β → ¬α) → ((¬β → α) → β))

In one of my problem sheets, I am told that I am allowed to use the following theorem:
if

⊢ (α → α)

⊢ (α → α) → (α → α)

My attempt to solve/prove the second one 
⊢ (α → α) → (α → α)
choose 2 axioms which match.

α →α

β→α

γ→α

(α → (α → α) → ((α → α) → (α → α))

I'm struggling to see an obvious way of proving the theorem.

Is it provable? And if so, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that there is a typo in Ax.2. The correct formula is : $((α → (β → γ) → ((α → β) → (α → γ)))$ . See [List of axiom system for propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_negation).

Comment: That's true. Thanks I will fix it.

Comment: @Jared Fixed it for you ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Your "correct formula" has six left brackets and only five right brackets ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof of $\alpha \to \alpha$:

\begin{array}{lll}
1 & (\alpha \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha) \to ((\alpha \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) &A2\\
2 & \alpha \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha & A1\\
3 & (\alpha \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)& MP \ 1,2\\
4 & \alpha \to (\alpha \to \alpha) & A1\\
5 & \alpha \to \alpha & MP \ 3,4\\
\end{array}

To get a proof of $(\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)$, simply substitute $\alpha \to \alpha$ for $\alpha$ in the previous proof:

\begin{array}{lll}
1 & ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) \to (((\alpha \to \alpha) \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha))) \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha))) &A2\\
2 & (\alpha \to \alpha) \to (((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) \to (\alpha \to \alpha) & A1\\
3 & ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha))) \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha))& MP \ 1,2\\
4 & (\alpha \to \alpha) \to ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)) & A1\\
5 & (\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha) & MP \ 3,4\\
\end{array}

Notice how you can always do this substitution trick: once you have proving something using some statements variables, you can always substitute any complex statement for those variables. That is, once you have proven that $\vdash \alpha \to \alpha$, then you can immediately conclude that  $\vdash (\alpha \to \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \alpha)$ without having to write out an actual derivation.

Comment: That's true. I Fixed that.

Comment: 2. (α → (β → γ) → ((α → β) → (α → γ)) second axiom will be like this.

Comment: Did you prove depends on my previous version ?

Comment: I got it! Big Thanks. How to find like this examples so I can Practice ?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers show how to prove $P\to P$ and then set $P\equiv(\alpha\to\alpha)$. This works, of course.

But your particular goal can be reached faster with the axioms you have:

- $(\alpha\to(\alpha\to\alpha))$
- $(\alpha\to(\alpha\to\alpha))\to((\alpha\to\alpha)\to(\alpha\to\alpha))$

are instaces of your axioms 1 and 2, respectively.

Now use Modus Ponens *once* and you're done.

Comment: If compared with the shortest condensed detachment proof, this makes for an example of how a substitution and detachment proof can be have fewer detachments than the shortest condensed detachment proof.

Answer (score 2):

A logical axiom is a [*schema* (plural: *schemata*, or *schemas*)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/#UsesSche) i.e. a "template" that we can use to produce infinitely many formulas all having the same patter.

Thus, all the following formulas are instances of the axiom schema A.1 :

> $p \to (q \to p), p \to (p \to p), (p\to q) \to (r \to (p \to q))$, etc.

The same holds for theorems, i.e. logical (schematic) formulas derived from axioms.

Thus $\vdash \alpha \to \alpha$ is again a schema, meaning that every instance of it is derivable in the calculus :

> $p \to p, q \to q, (p \to q) \to (p \to q), (p \to p) \to (p \to p)$, etc.

---

The proof of $\vdash \alpha \to \alpha$ is quite simple :

1) $\vdash \alpha \to ((\beta \to \alpha) \to \alpha)$ --- Ax.1

2) $\vdash \alpha \to(\beta \to \alpha)$ --- Ax.1

3) $\vdash (1) \to ((2) \to (\alpha \to \alpha))$ --- Ax.2

> 4) $\vdash \alpha \to \alpha$ --- from 3), 1) and 2) by *Modus Ponens* twice.

---

---

For an alternative approach, see the post [A Logical Axiom that is Not a Schema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472459/a-logical-axiom-that-is-not-a-schema-scheme).

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - I'm quite sure it's a typo. (A1)-(A2-corrected)-(A3) is the well-known Mendelson's axiom system for prop logic. The formula written by the OP is not a tautology.

Comment: Thanks but for (α→α)→ (α→α)) will same or different?

Comment: That's true I fix it.